# Expressing this result in different coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, derivatives, vector-fields, calculus

Is there a neat way to express this in Cylindrical and Spherical coordinate systems?
$(\vec{A}\boldsymbol{\cdot }\nabla)\vec{B}$


Reference: this occurs quite frequently in Electrodynamics books including Griffiths. Everywhere it is evaluated in Cartesian - Coordinate form.

Comment: This question is about math, not physics.

Answer (score 1):

In arbitrary coordinates the inner product is
$$\mathrm u\boldsymbol\cdot\mathrm v=\langle \mathrm{u},\mathrm v\rangle=u^iv_i$$
And the nabla operator is
$$\nabla=\sum_{i}\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}}\mathrm{e}_i\partial_{i}$$
Combine these expressions to yield what you want in any coordinate system you choose.

Comment: I would like to emphasize here that $v$ must be a covector for this to work. If $v$ is a vector, you will need to "index lower" it using the metric.